# Fixed background scroll like effect relative to background on seperate element

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, parallax

I was wondering if the community can help me out. I have a very specific request. I would like to achieve the following effect: 
https://iphone.artsy.net/ 
or
http://www.discovershadow.com/

To create a background-attachment:fixed like presentation of a mobile app that changes together with the background color. I've seen this "effect" on other pages as well but can't put a finger on it if it has a name or not. I know one way is to achieve it is to have the app and background in one image and do it all in css. However I would like to achieve this by having the two separate but change content relative to each other.

I know obvious would be javascript but since I have limited skills in that area  and can't write complex functions other than finding code snippets on stackoverflow and implementing them in my project. I looked into the code on the linked page but it feels heavy to figure it out and try to write my own based on it.

So I was wondering if anyone has written a code like this before and is willing to share with me. Would be greatly appreciated but i understand it can be a big work to do it.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);

Solved the problem with css only.